# opencv_traincascade error message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, emgucv

I tried to create my own haar cascade to detect licence plate recognition I used 99 positives images 140*45 and 2645 negatives images and I launch the training with:

```
C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-x86_2.4.0.1717\bin\x86\opencv_traincascade.exe -data classifier -vec samples1.vec -bg negative.txt -numStages 3 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -numPos 50 -numNeg 100 -w 60 -h 40 -precalcValBuffSize 256 -precalcdxbufSize 256
```

and then I got this error

**  Opencv error : Assertion failed <_img.rows * _img.cols ==vecSize> in unknown function file E:\work\emgucv_32bit_vc\opencv\apps\traincascade\imagestorage.cpp, line 151   **

please help

`